# Invalid event target in Angular with custom event on the component, not on the html element

Tags: angular

In parentComponent

```
template: `<childA #test></childA>`
@ViewChild('test') test: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {

  this.test$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.test.nativeElement, 'customEvent');
}
```

I'm trying to make an Observable over the event which occurs inside of the `childA` component but I'm getting the `Invalid event target` error at the moment. What did I miss?

**EDIT**

I found out I get this error when I attach `subscribe` to it. For instance, `Observable.fromEvent(this.test.nativeElement, 'customEvent').subscribe(ev => console.log(ev));`

Still no idea why I get this error though.

Comment: I've tested it out with the native events(click etc) and it works fine. I guess there's got to be something I'm missing with the custom event via `eventemitter` from the child component.

Comment: I think the problem results from the try that assigns the local value on the component, not the native element. I've bypassed it by using eventemitter from the child component.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue with a customEvent in NG 8 but only when I run `ng test --code-coverage`. Can you try removing `Observable` so it will look like `this.test$ = fromEvent(this.test.nativeElement, 'customEvent');`